# SoftLayer status ID definitions across classes

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

It seems that the SoftLayer API uses integer representation/mapping for properties that contain some kind of status information about a given object.

Like "userStatus", or "accountStatusId", etc..

However, it's only for user related statuses that the status ID's are actually documented in the SoftLayer_User_Customer_Status class.

But if you, for instance, take the "accountStatusId" property in the SoftLayer_Account class, there doesn't seem to be any clear definitions on what those numeric values actually represent.

They seem to be the same as those defined in SoftLayer_User_Customer_Status, but that's just an observation/guess.

**TL;DR**

Do the values in the "accountStatusId" property, in the SoftLayer_Account class, mean the same thing as the ones defined for "SoftLayer_User_Customer_Status"?

So that:

```
1001 = Active
1002 = Disabled
1003 = Inactive
```

etc..

Or are there other definitions, and if so, what are they? Could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you are right the status are:

```
1001 = Active
1002 = Disabled
1003 = Inactive
```

there is no more that those for the account